# Linux iptables issue

Tags: linux, kernel, iptables

I've compiled a kernel which include USB wifi adapter drivers for my OnePlus 3 phone. I compiled the kernel for Oreo and everything is working as expected. But with the same settings I compiled a kernel for Pie. 
The problem is when I create an Access Point using hostapd, I can connect to it from my other devices, but unable to even ping the Access Point. On Oreo there's no such issue. I've tried adding some firewall rules clearing them etc. Everything failed. I'd like to know what all possibilities there are in linux for blocking a ping or any other requests to it. Is it only limited to iptables?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by "you can connect"?

Comment: By connect i mean im able to get ip from dhcp. Thats all. Can't ping or access anything. I want to connect to a captive portal running under lighttpd. But everything is getting blocked..

Comment: The output of `ip r` and `ip a` may shed some light on this issue.

Comment: I'll try that. I was going to test this and my phone's power switch gone bad. Can't turn on. I'll have to but from China.. Will try and get back. Thanks

Comment: Ip r shows the correct route entry. One thing I noticed from dmesg is something like "avc denied ioctl unix_dgram_socket hostapd" . Does this message have to do anything with my issue? I can connect multiple devices on the AP running hostapd. All nodes can ping and access each other but to and from the AP i cant access anything. Selinux is set to permissive.